# Relative Computational Complexity for Channelizer Implementations

Tags: fft, dsp-core, filtering, polyphase

Suppose I want to separate a broadband input signal into multiple narrow subbands using an FFT-based analysis filter bank. The filter bank uses a prototype lowpass filter and is implemented using a polyphase structure.

[See Matlab's Channelizer class](https://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/dsp.channelizer-class.html) 
[image: DFT Matrix]

Does it require fewer FLOPS (floating point operations) to do the filtering in the frequency domain as a multiplication and sum or as a convolution in the time domain? Matlab implements the filtering in the time domain.

Answer (score 3):

For sufficiently long filters, it's usually more efficient to implement the individual filters as FFT-based fast convolution, indeed!

Now, whether something is faster than something else really doesn't depend on the FLOPs alone, but also on the kind of operation, the memory / bandwidth requirements and so on.

In fact, this question was raised in the context of [GNU Radio](http://gnuradio.org)'s [PFB channelizer](http://www.trondeau.com/examples/2014/1/23/pfb-channelizers-and-synthesizers.html); luckily, Tom Rondeau wrote a short [article](http://www.trondeau.com/blog/2014/2/27/to-use-or-not-to-use-fft-filters.html) on his findings whether direct FIRs or FFT filters in the individual branches are beneficial in the environment of general purpose computers running his [PFB implementation](https://gnuradio.org/doc/doxygen/classgr_1_1filter_1_1pfb__channelizer__ccf.html).

From that article:

[image: Comparison]

Now, for *GPU-based* channelizers, this might be a bit different. Not an expert here, but I'd like to point you to Mr. Jan Krämer's pretty nice presentation from FOSDEM17's SDR Devroom on [*GPU-Enabled Polyphase Filterbanks*](https://fosdem.org/2017/schedule/event/gpupfb/)("Everyday I'm shuffling") (slides [here](https://fosdem.org/2017/schedule/event/gpupfb/attachments/slides/1751/export/events/attachments/gpupfb/slides/1751/GEN_PFB_CUDA.pdf)):

[image: Screenshot from Video]

The talk highlights that the same number of ops, depending on your hardware, and memory layout, mean a very different throughput.